# KineticJS transform image to a trapezium

Tags: html, image, image-processing, kineticjs

Is it possible to apply transformations to an image to transform it in a trapezium?

The image initial state is a rectangulum.
The way my scene is build, I have a polygon that allows dragging on the edges, and an image with the same size and position.

I would like the image to have the same shape of the polygon aways, so it would became a trapezium when one polygon axis is dragged. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about something like an isosceles trapezoid rather than a simple rectangle.

**The answer is No, but Yes...**

No, not possible with 2D transforms--canvas.getContext("2d").  That's because 2d transforms use a 3x3 matrix that only makes parallel transforms.  Since a trapezoid is non-parallel, you cannot possibly transform an image (rectangle) into a trapezoid.

But, Yes...you *can* use webGL (canvas 3D transforms) to do non-parallel transforms and therefore you can use canvas 3D to convert an image into a trapezoid.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any tutorial of how doing this? I'm searching the web quite extensively but could not find anything of use.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is "perspective transforms".  Perspective transforms will distort an image so it appears to move in 3D space. Giles Thomas and Tony Parisi have put together a fantastic series of beginning WebGL tutorials that are well worth a look: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=28   Be sure to have plenty of coffee before you start--these tutorials are excellent but they will challenge your brain!